# A pre-coded web-based client that can connect to OSCAR/AIM and/or GCHAT that I can host on my web server?

Tags: instant-messaging, aim, aol, instantmessenger

Does anyone know of a readymade web-based client that I can host on my personal web server to be able to connect to AIM? I guess I'm looking for more of a solution like gmail-lite (a php coded client that connects to gmail, hosted on your web server) but for instant messaging. Please help, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I don't know of any that do both, but I've used this with GChat: http://www.igniterealtime.org/projects/sparkweb/index.jsp

Answer (score 0):

Any web-based XMPP client (like [JWChat](http://blog.jwchat.org/jwchat/)) + XMPP AIM transport.

Or (I don't know whether this is still current):

Any web-based XMPP client connected to [AIM's XMPP service](http://florianjensen.com/2008/01/17/aol-adopting-xmpp-aka-jabber/).