# Creating website containing google talk messenger, yahoo messenger and hotmail messenger like ebuddy

Tags: java, php, jsp, xmpp, instantmessenger

i am creating a website containing all this messenger mentioned above. I just want to know that which language should i use to embed all this messenger on one website .. ? shall i use PHP / JSP / any other server scripting ? also suggest me some method to embed all this messenger to one web page. I am newbie in web development. also i want to use XMPP protocol and also other protocol which are useful in chatting. Hope you people help me . Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

A same kind of question has been answered at

[A pre-coded web-based client that can connect to OSCAR/AIM and/or GCHAT that I can host on my web server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/972113/a-pre-coded-web-based-client-that-can-connect-to-oscar-aim-and-or-gchat-that-i-ca).

Please search existing question-answers before posting and don't forget to up-vote/mark useful answers.

Stackoverflow needs your active participation to keep itself away from mess of duplication and to stay as an excellent and good quality helping hand for techies.

Appreciate your positive participation.

Comment: No need to beat a dead horse.